# Request to Graph API from Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to understand how the request to the Graph API works from Azure Functions.

From the App Service of my Azure Functions, I generated the Active Directoy App, and from there, I add in the "API Permissions" to be able to do requests to the Graph API.

[image]

My doubts are the following:

1- When I access the endpoint of my AAD App (____.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me), could I use the access token that it returns to make the request to the Graph API? I have done some testing but it returns the following error:
**CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217**

2- I have also tried to make a request to the endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT-ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token so that it should return an access token to make the request to the API of Graph. But I am getting the next error:
**The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'**

To do this tries, I am using Postman/Insomnia. But I am not very sure how to continue trying.

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- When I access the endpoint of my AAD App
> (____.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me), could I use the access token that
> it returns to make the request to the Graph API?

Yes, you can. You need to add `["resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"]` to **additionalLoginParams** under **authsettings**. Refer to [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-app-service/azure-app-service-easyauth-and-azure-active-directory-flows/ba-p/1099890) for more details.

[image]

> 2- I have also tried to make a request to the endpoint:
> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT-ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BTENANT-ID%5D/oauth2/v2.0/token) so
> that it should return an access token to make the request to the API
> of Graph. But I am getting the next error: The request body must
> contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

To call this endpoint, you will need some parameters, refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) for more details.

Another thing is that there are two kinds of **API permissions**, **Delegated permission** and A**pplication permission**. You should use Delegated permission instead of Application permission.

Reference:

[Difference between Azure App Registration -‘Delegated’ and ‘Application’ Permission](http://abhijitkakade.com/2020/04/difference-between-azure-app-registration-delegated-and-application-permission/)

Comment: Thank you very much Tony!! The only thing I was missing was to  ["resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"] to additionalLoginParams under authsettings.